# How to make a dot graph in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

[I have three columns, 1) week, 2) Budget_numbers, 3) Actual_numbers. When I try to make a graph: 1) out of the axis, and 2) + 3) as my y-axis -
I get an output where I only have the numbers 1 and 2 on my y-axis even though the columns 2) and 3) have numbers between 40.000 - 50.000 ]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoAv8.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Now it is edited, hopefully somebody can better answer on this :)

Comment: If you use a scatter chart, you can define a column thats used for the x-axis and columns that will be used for the y-axis. Also set the data to "don't summarize"